# Spring Configuration file error

Tags: java, spring, jms, jmstemplate, spring-jms

I am trying to run a simple program using a spring configuration file. In the configuration I am creating a bean for the JMS template. When I run it from eclipse everything works perfect but if I try to run it from the command line I get the following error.

> Error creatign bean with name JMSTEMPLATE definded in class path resource [`config.xml`]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`: `javax/jms/JMSException`

Does anyone know why this could be? I've double checked my class path and it is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are forgetting to include the `jms.jar` in your [classpath](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/classpath.html).

Comment: There was a small typo that took me forever to find, but this was the root of it all.

Answer (score 1):

Are you including JMS jars in your classpath? This error suggests that they are missing at runtime.